# Не линкуется библиотека xblas

Tags: c++, library

Собрал библиотеку по инструкции с сайта следующими командами:

```
wget http://www.netlib.org/xblas/xblas.tar.gz
tar xvf xblas.tar.gz
cd xblas
autoconf
CC=gcc FC=gfortran ./configure
m4 Makefile.m4 >Makefile
make makefiles
make
```

После полученную библиотеку скопировал `/usr/local/lib/`
В сборку добавил флаг `-lxblas`

После чего получил ошибку

```
undefined reference to `BLAS_dsum_x(int, double const*, int, double*, blas_prec_type)'
```

Comment: Решение где-то [тут](/questions/536546/)

Comment: системная либа чем-то не угодила или сборка это самоцель?